# HtmlUnit - After login to website the page doesn't redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, authentication, htmlunit

I'm trying to use HtmlUnit to get data fom a web site,
so far i managed to enter the data needed in order to login (username & password).

The problem begins with the fact that the website login form dosent have a submit button, instead there is an href that has an onClick JavaScript function  `(onclick="login_submit())`
that verify data and then call `window.location = "index.php";`

So i tried clicking the href using:

```
HtmlAnchor anchor = page.getAnchorByText("כניסה");
page = anchor.click();
```

and tried:

```
page.executeJavaScript(javaScriptCode);
```

but the page variable dosent get the expected page, it got the same url as before clicking and there is no redirection. Once the `login_submit()` function is called there is a label that indicates " login.." but nothing happens from there.

Here is the code:

```
// javascript login_submit() -- this is not my website and not my JS code so ive deleted some things:

function login_submit()
{
    if(!LOGIN_SUBMIT_PROCESSED)
    {
        var approved = true;
        var admin_user_username_field = document.getElementById('admin_user_username');
        var admin_user_username_error = document.getElementById('admin_user_username_error');
        var admin_user_password_field = document.getElementById('admin_user_password');
        var admin_user_password_error = document.getElementById('admin_user_password_error');

        admin_user_username_field.className = "login_form_field_input_text";
        admin_user_username_error.style.display = 'none';
        admin_user_password_field.className = "login_form_field_input_text";
        admin_user_password_error.style.display = 'none';

        if(admin_user_username_field.value.length == 0)
        {
            //do something
        }
        if(admin_user_password_field.value.length == 0)
        {
            //do something
        }
        if(approved)
        {
            LOGIN_SUBMIT_PROCESSED = true;
            document.getElementById("login_form_options").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("login_form_process").style.display = "";

            var http_request = new XHConn();
            http_request.connect(
                "login_submit.php?cache="+string_unique(),
                "POST",
                "form_anti_bot_code="+encodeURIComponent(form_anti_bot_code_field.value)
                + "&admin_user_username="+encodeURIComponent(admin_user_username_field.value)
                + "&admin_user_password="+encodeURIComponent(admin_user_password_field.value),
                function(response,callback_data)
                {
                    if(response.readyState == 4)
                    {
                        if(response.status == 200)
                        {
                            //alert(response.responseText);
                            try
                            {
                                var json_response = JSON.parse(response.responseText);

                                if(json_response["error_code"] == "0")
                                {
                                    window.location = "index.php";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //do something
                                }
                            }
                            catch(error)
                            {
                                alert(error);
                            }
                        }

                        LOGIN_SUBMIT_PROCESSED = false;
                    }
                },
                null
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
    //webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);


    HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient
            .getPage(url);
    HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("login_form");

    form.getInputByName("admin_user_username").setValueAttribute("XXXXX"); 
    HtmlInput passWordInput = form.getInputByName("admin_user_password");
    passWordInput.removeAttribute("disabled");
    passWordInput.setValueAttribute("XXXXXX"); 

    HtmlAnchor anchor = page.getAnchorByText("Login");
    page = anchor.click();
    System.out.println(page.getBody().asText());
    webClient.close();
}
```

I know for a fact after some testing that the login data is ok, href is clicked and there is an indicator that login is being proccesed.
the main problem is that its not redirecting and dont get the "index.php" page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and it should do the trick:

WebWindow window = page.getEnclosingWindow();

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick:

```
final HtmlPage page2 = page.getElementById("Login_Button").click();
```